# Installing Github project to localhost and run

Tags: node.js

https://github.com/hach-que/OpenExchange.git

I want to Install this GitHub project to localhost and run this, I am new into node so don't have much idea, I am able to clone it but it is not running?

[Error which I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UC1b1.png)

Comment: install node.js then try google how to run a simple nodejs server, when it show the error that is time you should ask in stackoverflow

Comment: I tried but it is returning error class not defined and also there no package.json file.
For starting the server I am trying "node run.js"

Comment: well you can ask the github owner i try to include the class but not work, you could show the class error for more help

Comment: I have added the screenshot please have a look

Comment: I think this code not finish base on his last commit message, something must be correct

Comment: What can we do now?

Answer (score 0):

How do you run it? Explain us to know the exact problem?

Here are the steps to run a GitHub project on your machine.

How to run GitHub project into your localhost:

1. First clone it from GitHub with `git clone` command
   e.g.

   ```
   git clone https://github.com/hach-que/OpenExchange.git
   ```
2. Type in your cmd: `cd OpenExchange`
3. Run this command `npm intall`, it will install all required dependencies and modules.
4. Type `node run.js` to run. (This is different, incase the server file has some different names, sometimes it has `index.js` or `app.js`.  Run as per your server file)
5. Open Chrome, run with your port number. E.g. `localhost:1337`

Thanks, Happy learning

Comment: there are no pakage.json. the error is Class object not define but it already require in run.js

Comment: I tried exactly the same procedure and got the error, I have added the screenshot in the question please have a look.

Comment: That, git projects has some error, it's still not fully projects, he keeps some file hidden, that why there is an error.

Comment: Is it require some dependency to install?

Comment: Yes, there might be some crypto dependencies. ask to the author, how he made the module and ask what dependencies he used.